# need to cover if condition in a function in angular using Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

Below is the function which I have written in a angular service-

```
setUSerprofile()
{
  if (this.finalHeadersfromoAuthUtils)
      this.userprofile =
        this.finalHeadersfromoAuthUtils['ext-user-profile-compressed']
}
```

I need to write test cases to cover it 100 %. 'this.finalHeadersfromoAuthUtil' is something which is set by a service call response right before this method is executed.

I tried below test cases -

```
it('should call setuserprofile method with value inoauthutil',()=>{
service.finalHeadersfromoAuthUtils={
  "user-agent":"mozilla"
}
const input={
  "user-agent":"mozilla"
}
service.userprofile=input

service.setUSerprofile()

const res=jest.spyOn(service,"setUSerprofile")
expect(res).toHaveBeenCalled()

})
```

'Service' is the instace of service class containing function which we are trying to cover.

Thanks, Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not really clear what your question is, please try to reframe it. Generally, there seems to be some hick ups with the naming of the fields - in the the method itself you use the attribute ext-user-profile-compressed, but this does not exist in the test input. Also, spying the method setUSerprofile after it was called won't work and since is the method you want to test, you definitely should not spy on it. And setUSerprofile is not properly cased either ;)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to cover the function now.